# Android HttpsURLConnection on 2.3.4 OutOfMemoryError while uploading Large File (byte[] in memory)

Tags: android, out-of-memory, httpurlconnection, large-files

I'm trying to upload a large file ~10 MB on server and realized that on 2.3.4 the stream is written in memory first before writing to server, i confirm this behavior by looking into Heap Memory Dump, because of this for large file it causes OutOfMemory exception. I don't see the same behavior on 4.2 device.

Following is the code I'm using:

```
    URL url = new URL(uri);
    connection = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    connection.setDoOutput(true);
    connection.setRequestMethod("PUT");
    connection.setRequestProperty("content-type", "");
    connection.setRequestProperty("Accept-Encoding", "");                                    
    connection.setFixedLengthStreamingMode((int)totalBytes);
    out = new BufferedOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
    fis = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));

    byte[] buffer = new byte[32 * 1024];
    int bytesRead = 0;
    int totalBytesRead = 0;
    while ((bytesRead = fis.read(buffer)) != -1)
    {
        totalBytesRead = totalBytesRead + bytesRead;                
            out.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);// OOM Error                
    }

    out.flush();
```

Answer (score 1):

I filed a bug with google-android and they claim it's fixed for GingerBread release but I'm still able to replicate the issue in 2.3.4

Link to the bug https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=53946 and 
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=3164

I ended up using HttpClient for **Eclair**, **Froyo**, **GingerBread**
and HttpURLConnection for **HoneyComb** and above